# Recycle boundary condition

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, physics, modeling

I'm having the following issue that can not find a solution , by using this boundary condition

```
u[0, t] == 2 u[1, t]
```

that Mathematica does not understand, someone please help me!

```
s = NDSolve[
  {
   D[u[x, t], t] == -D[u[x, t], x] - u[x, t],
   u[x, 0] == 1,

   u[0, t] == 2 u[1, t]
   },

  {u[x, t]},

  {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1},

  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "TemporalVariable" -> t}}]
```

I'm getting this error message :

> NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition u[0,t]==2u[1,t] is not specified on
>   a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain.

I have already presented a similar problem here, but the reasoning suggested is not a good solution for my case.

What strategies do you know to treat this problem ? I appreciate any help...

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to make use of the method suggested in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136325/1871), but since this equation is simpler, we can solve it by making a change of variable

$$u(x,t)=\frac{v(x,t)}{x+1}$$

I'll use [`DChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871) for the task.

```
set = {D[u[x, t], t] == -D[u[x, t], x] - u[x, t], u[x, 0] == 1, u[0, t] == 2 u[1, t]};

newset = DChange[set, u[x, t] == 1/(1 + x) v[x, t]]

mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
newsol = NDSolveValue[newset, v, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tend}, Method -> mol[201]]

Plot[{newsol[x, t]/(1 + x) /. x -> 0, 2 newsol[x, t]/(1 + x) /. x -> 1} // Evaluate, {t, 
  0, tend}, PlotStyle -> {Green, {Dashed, Red, Thick}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[newsol[x, t]/(1 + x), {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There's some noise at the discontinuity, but I think the result is still acceptable.