# How to solve PDE with periodic and anti-periodic b.c.?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, complex, boundary-conditions

I need to solve the PDE for a complex function $A(x,t)=A_r(x,t)+iA_i(x,t)$

```
eq = D[A[x, t], t] + 1/4*Conjugate[A[x, t]]*A[x, t]^2 - D[A[x, t], {x, 2}] - 2*A[x, t] == 0;
```

over $[-L,L]$ and $[0,t_\text{max}]$.
The equation is subject to a random initial condition and the boundary conditions as follows: $A_r(-L,t)=A_r(L,t)$ and $A_i(-L,t)=-A_i(L,t)$

```
L = 30; tmax = 30;
ini[x_] = 1/10*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20], SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 5][x/(2*L)];
ibcs = {Re[A[-L, t]] == Re[A[L, t]], Im[A[-L, t]] == -Im[A[L, t]], A[x, 0] == ini[x]};
```

Then, I solve it with `NDSolve`

```
sol = NDSolve[{eq, ibcs}, A, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
             Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
             "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
             "MinPoints" -> 201, "MaxPoints" -> 201, 
             "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, AccuracyGoal -> 20]
```

But I received the error

> NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition Im[A[-30,t]]==-Im[A[30,t]] is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain.>>

I didn't understand the error. Why the boundary conditions (bcs) must be specified on a single edge. Should not we set the bcs at both sides?
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thank for @xzczd's comment:

I just knew that `NDSolve` could not handle anti-periodic bc.
Yes, the equation can be solved with a periodic bc:

```
periodbcs = {A[-L, t] == A[L, t], A[x, 0] == ini[x]}
```

**But the solution should be incorrect because the solution is a real function** by observing its imaginary part.

```
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[Im[A[x, t] /. sol]], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 Contours -> 10, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "Ai", ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Response to @user64494's comment:

Yes, I can split the real and imaginary parts by writing the 2nd term as

$(A^\ast A)A=\vert A\vert^2A=(A_r^2+A_i^2)(A_r+i A_i)=A_r^3+A_i^2A_r+i(A_r^2A_i+A_i^3)$

Then the equation can be split into

```
eqs = {D[Ar[x, t], t] + 1/4*(Ar[x, t]^3+Ai[x, t]^2*Ar[x, t]) - D[Ar[x, t], {x, 2}] - 2*Ar[x, t] == 0,
D[Ai[x, t], t] + 1/4*(Ai[x, t]^3+Ar[x, t]^2*Ai[x, t]) - D[Ai[x, t], {x, 2}] - 2*Ai[x, t] == 0};
```

But I don't know how to make an anti-periodic initial condition (`Ai[x, 0] = inianti[x]`) to be consistent with the boundary condition.

```
ibcs = {Ar[-L, t] == Ar[L, t], Ai[-L, t] == -Ai[L, t], Ar[x, 0] == ini[x], Ai[x, 0] = inianti[x]};
```

Comment: @xzczd many thanks. Please see my update, where I can explain more clearly. Any workaround will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to split the real and imaginary parts in eq and ibcs?

Comment: @user64494 great idea. Please see my update. Any suggestion :)

Comment: Did you try to solve the split problem?

Comment: I haven’t because I don’t know how to get a random anti-periodic initial condition. Please help.

Comment: Did you try to solve the split problem without " a random anti-periodic initial condition"?

Comment: @xzczd many thanks! I need your help with solving it. It will be much better if you could impose a random ic also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pre-*v12* Solution

The approach [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109472/1871) is fully applicable to your problem. Anyway, the corresponding coding isn't trivial, so let me give an answer.

We start from the splitted equation system because `Re`, `Im`, `Conjugate` isn't that convenient for subsequent coding. The form of b.c.s are slightly modified, because both periodic b.c. and anti-periodic b.c. are set with one-sided difference formula in this method (which is different from using `PeriodicInterpolation` of `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``) and we need 4 constraints in `x` direction in total:

```
Clear[ini, inianti, Ai]
eqs = {D[Ar[x, t], t] + 1/4 (Ar[x, t]^3 + Ai[x, t]^2 Ar[x, t]) - D[Ar[x, t], {x, 2}] - 
     2 Ar[x, t] == 0, 
       D[Ai[x, t], t] + 1/4 (Ai[x, t]^3 + Ar[x, t]^2 Ai[x, t]) - D[Ai[x, t], {x, 2}] - 
     2 Ai[x, t] == 0};
ic = {Ar[x, 0] == ini[x], Ai[x, 0] == inianti[x]};
bc = {Ar[-L, t] == Ar[L, t], Ai[-L, t] == -Ai[L, t], 
   Derivative[1, 0][Ar][-L, t] == Derivative[1, 0][Ar][L, t], 
   Derivative[1, 0][Ai][-L, t] == -Derivative[1, 0][Ai][L, t]};
```

> ## Remark
>
> `Derivative[1, 0][Ar][-L, t] == Derivative[1, 0][Ar][L, t]` is added
>   because periodic b.c. implies the solution is smooth enough across the
>   boundary, but frankly speaking, I'm not familiar with
>   anti-periodic b.c. and not sure if `Derivative[1, 0][Ai][-L, t] ==
>   -Derivative[1, 0][Ai][L, t]` is correct, but do remember a supplement for derivative of `x` of `Ai` at the boundary is necessary, or a
>   particular solution won't be determined.

The i.c.s are simply generated randomly, they don't satisfy the b.c.s of course, but this should not be a big deal because the i.c.s will be slightly modified at the boundary to satisfy the b.c.s in the upcoming disretization step. (For more information about handling inconsistency between i.c. and b.c., you may want to check this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871). )

```
L = 30; tmax = 30;
SeedRandom[1];
ini = ListInterpolation[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20], {{-L, L}}];
inianti = ListInterpolation[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20], {{-L, L}}];
```

Finally, discretize the PDE system to an ODE system and solve, with the help of [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871):

```
points = 200; domain = {-L, L}; difforder = 4;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this code piece,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{Ar, Ai}[x, t], t, grid, difforder];
odebc = Map[ptoofunc, bc, {2}]
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
odeic = del /@ ptoofunc@ic;
ode = del /@ ptoofunc@eqs;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, 
   Table[v[x], {v, {Ar, Ai}}, {x, grid}], {t, 0, tmax}];
{solAr, solAi} = rebuild[#, grid, -1] & /@ sollst;
```

Check:

```
Plot[{solAr[-L, t], solAr[L, t], solAi[-L, t], solAi[L, t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Thick, Red, Dashed}, Dotted, Dotted}]
```

[image]

```
With[{d = Derivative[1, 0]}, 
 Plot[{d[solAr][-L, t], d[solAr][L, t], d[solAi][-L, t], d[solAi][L, t]}, {t, 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Thick, Red, Dashed}, Dotted, Dotted}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

---

## Suspicious *v12* Solution

Since *v12*, `"FiniteElement"` method can handle nonlinear PDE, so it's possible to solve the problem with `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` in principle. Nevertheless, the *v12* solution is suspicious:

```
test = NDSolveValue[{eqs, ic, 
     PeriodicBoundaryCondition[Ar[x, t], x == L, Function[x, x - 2 L]], 
     PeriodicBoundaryCondition[-Ai[x, t], x == L, Function[x, x - 2 L]]}, {Ar, Ai}, {t, 
     0, tmax}, {x, -L, L}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}]; // AbsoluteTiming

With[{d = Derivative[1, 0]}, 
 Plot[{d[test[[1]]][-L, t], d[test[[1]]][L, t], d[test[[2]]][-L, t], 
   d[test[[2]]][L, t]}, {t, 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Thick, Red, Dashed}, Dotted, Dotted}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

It's clear `Derivative[1, 0][Ar][-L, t] == Derivative[1, 0][Ar][L, t]` isn't satisfied. (Zero `NeumannValue` is set at $x=-L$? ) I guess the underlying issue may be related to that in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188109/1871).

Comment: Thank you very much @xzczd. I noticed that you didn't write a semicolon at the end of `odebc = Map[ptoofunc, bc, {2}]` on purpose to show me why you `Map` at level 2 :) Thanks!

Comment: a question: in `eqs` you defined the sequence of independent vars as `[x,t]`, why does in the solution, say, `solAr[t, -L]`, the sequence become `[t,x]`?

Comment: @Nobody  By default, the first variable of the function generated by `rebuild` is the variable amounts to time, if you want the original order, use e.g. `{solAr, solAi} = rebuild[#, grid, 2] & /@ sollst`.

Comment: @Nobody Oops, I've made a mistake in my original check, and the original `points` turns out to be too small. Corrected.

Comment: why did you say that the original result was incorrect? How did you identify that the problem results from the low mesh resolution? Thank you!

Comment: @Nobody I forgot to exchange the argument of `Derivative` i.e. I was calculating derivative of `t` in 2nd plot. It's not rare that too coarse a mesh causes problem, so I just tried increasing `points` once I saw the b.c.s aren't satisfied.

Comment: you said that by default the 1st var. of a function generated by `rebuild` is time-like variable, i.e. `rebuild[#, grid] & /@ sollst`, while `rebuild[#, grid, 2]` give vars. in the order of `[x,t]`. However, in the newset version, you used `rebuild[#, grid, -1]` instead. What is the meaning of `-1`, is it equivalent to `2`? @xzczd I am really confusing. Thank you.

Comment: also the last code piece doesn't give what is shown in the last figure.

Comment: @Nobody The last argument of `rebuild` is designed to be similar to that of `Part` i.e. `-1` means the last argument of generated function is the time-like variable. The code works as expected on my computer, have you re-executed all of the code?

Comment: it works now. Then, using 2 means what? And what If without the last argument in rebuild?

Comment: @nobody `2` means **2**nd argument of generated function is the time-like variable. As already mentioned, the first variable of the generated function is the time-like variable by default i.e. if the third argument of `rebuild` is omitted, the time-like variable will be 1st argument of generated function.

Comment: FYI @xzczd, yesterday, I found that `NDSolve` seems to be able to handle anti-periodic b.c. directly, see [PeriodicBoundaryCondition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicBoundaryCondition.html), especially the last item in the details :)

Comment: Btw @xzczd, how did you come up with the modified bcs $Ar_x(-L)=Ar_x(L)$ and $Ai_x(-L)=-Ai_x(L)$, meanwhile you believe these bcs are proper. Did you view it from a certain physical viewpoint? Thank you!

Comment: @Nobody Oh, seems that I'm in _v9_ for too long. Yes, _v12_ can handle anti-periodic b.c. of nonlinear PDE, but the solution given by `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` is suspicious, see my update. To be honest, I'm not sure if my supplement for the anti-periodic b.c. is correct, but `Derivative[1, 0][Ar][-L, t] == Derivative[1, 0][Ar][L, t]` should be correct, at least this is how periodic b.c. is implemented in ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative``. It essentially implies the solution is smooth enough across the boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the information @xzczd. I have reconsidered the b.c.s., which should be $Ar(−L)=Ar(L)=Ai(−L)=Ai(L)=0$, $Ar_x(−L)=Ar_x(L)$ and $Ai_x(−L)=-Ai_x(L)$. Can you implement the bcs? With these b.c.s. I think the result of your `pdetoode` should be the same as v12 FEM solution :)

Comment: @Nobody The system is overdetermined with this b.c.s, $Ar(−L)=Ar(L)=Ai(−L)=Ai(L)=0$ already determines a solution.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you so much! @xzczd I have tried $Ar(−L)=Ar(L)=Ai(−L)=Ai(L)=0$ in the `pdetoode`, but the solution is **not** smooth across the boundary. I believe your two derivatives bcs are essentially correct, to be consistent in my problem, i must enforce that Dirichlet bcs. Please give some suggestion. Many thanks!

Comment: @Nobody It's impossible to enforce all these 6 b.c.s together, AFAIK. If $L$ is an approximation for `Infinity`, then a larger `L` might help. Also, you should check if the PDE itself is correct.

Comment: You are so clever @xzczd, why did you guess the proper bcs should be $Ai_x(−L)=−Ai_x(L)$. Actually, when I tried with `Derivative[1, 0][Ai][-L, t] == Derivative[1, 0][Ai][L, t]`, the code run a long time without finding a solution. Then I terminate manually. It could be implying that $Ai_x(−L)=Ai_x(L)$ is improper.

Comment: @Nobody It's based on the following assumption: anti-periodic b.c. implies the piecewise function $\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
 & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 {A_i}(x) & x<L \\
 -{A_i}(x) & x\geq L \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array} \right.$ is smooth around $x=L$.